# Asp.Net Core Identity RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an AccountController for authorization with Asp.Net Core Identity. If successful, I make a RedirectToAction and want to redirect the user to "returnUrl", but the redirection does not work correctly.

When the application opens, I am redirected to the authorization page (this is correct) and the URL looks like this:

```
https://localhost:7008/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
```

or if I requested an administration page

```
https://localhost:7008/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin
```

After successful authorization, I get a 404 error, since RedirectToAction eventually generates such URLs:

```
https://localhost:7008/Account/%2F
https://localhost:7008/Account/%2FAdmin
```

As if the Account controller is still present in the URL!

Here are the controller methods:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl) {
  ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Login);
    if (user != null) {
      await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
      var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false, false);
      if (result.Succeeded) {
        return RedirectToAction(returnUrl ?? "/");
      }
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(LoginModel.Login), "Invalid login or password!");
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Program.cs:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` method is used to redirect to specified `action` instead of rendering the HTML. In this case, the browser receives the redirect notification and make a new request for the specified action. In this case, the browser receives the redirect notification and make a new request for the specified action.

`Redirect` method is used to redirect to specified `URL` instead of rendering HTML. In this case, the browser receives the redirect notification and make a new request for the specified URL.

You use RedirectToAction("/"), so application is looking for action named "/". If you would use Redirect("/") instead, you would get redirected to main page.

***RedirectToAction("something"):***

```
https://localhost:7008/Account/something
```

***Redirect("something"):***

```
https://localhost:7008/something
```

https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/return-view-vs-return-redirecttoaction-vs-return-redirect-vs-return-redirecttoroute

I don't know what you want to achieve so I suggest one of the following:

```cs
return Redirect(returnUrl);

return Redirect("ControllerName/" + returnUrl);

return RedirectToAction("ActionName", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });

return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `returnUrl` parameter contains not an action name but just a relative url path.

Try to use `Redirect(string url)` method instead of `RedirectToAction(string actionName)`.